# Configuring Seafile/Seahub to use mail command

Tags: email, exim, seafile-server

Just installed an instance of [Seafile](http://seafile.com) on my CentOS server.   It works OK, except for email notifications.  Some of the documentation on configuring email [is missing](http://manual.seafile.com/config/email.html) from the online manual (page is 404'ed as of 2014-08-18 9:30a EDT).  The only other email related documtation I found was for [configuring SMTP](http://manual.seafile.com/config/seahub_settings_py.html).

Is there a way to set Seafile/Seahub up to use the mail command (postfix/exim/ect) instead of SMTP?  I don't want to use my personal email credentials in the config file, and my SMTP service will not allow anonymous message delivery.

Answer (score 5):

In my Googling, it looks like they have removed the ability to pipe to an MTA (like sendmail or postfix or exim).  Instead, they now require you to provide an SMTP server and optional parameters for SMTP Auth.

The solution is straightforward.  You are quite likely already running an SMTP Server on your local machine that is listening on 127.0.0.1:25 (localhost port 25).  Simply configure the host and port to that, and follow the instructions in Note 2:

> Note2: If you want to use the Email service without authentication
>   leave EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD blank (''). (But notice
>   that the emails then will be sent without a From: address.)

The "without a From: address" is fine, your local mail server will add that for you (in what is typically called a fix-up mode when messages are submitted locally).  It will be whatever user you are running the webserver as @ the hostname of the machine.

An even better option would be to have your local mail server configured to support SMTP Auth.  To do this, you create a user which is really only intended to send email and configure that user in the settings.  For example, create a user named 'notifier', set the password to something long and complicated, then configure the two settings that were omitted above to the username (likely without the @hostname part) and the password.

You said you're running Exim, so let's do a little looking under the hood.  Is it nstalled from source?  From RPM?  Does the exim.conf have an authenticators section that defines PLAIN or LOGIN authentication types?  If yes, then it will likely work with a system account and password out of the box.  If it doesn't have those authenticators, then you'll have to add them, and it should be as simple as the authenticators code segment (using PAM) shown in https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/AuthenticatedSmtpUsingPam.  I don't think you'll need to recompile because linking against PAM is pretty standard for modern Exim builds.  The RPMs that I build for myself are based off of the AtRPMS source and IIRC, and they link to PAM by default.

Comment: I'm running exim on this box.

Comment: Thanks - to answer your question, it is managed with Yum.  I'm out of the office for a few days but will poke around next week and follow up as needed.